# Contracting a list of nodes in networkx

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph, networkx

i have a dictionary with nodes:

```
supernodes = list(nx.connected_components(G1))
```

the result of `print(supernodes)` is:

```
[{1, 2, 3, 5}, {8, 6}, {7, 9, 10, 12, 13}, {4}, {11}, {14}, {15}]
```

how can i merge each list to a node? I found this function `nx.contracted_nodes(G, (1, 3))` but how can i put `{1,2,3,5}, {8,6}` etc and create the 7  contracted nodes?

Comment: What do you want to your output to be? It's not clear how you want to represent the contracted nodes.

Comment: @Imran the output i want to be a graph with 7 nodes. One node for `{1, 2, 3, 5}`, one node for`{8, 6}`, one for `{7, 9, 10, 12, 13}`, one for `{4}` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this:

```
import networkx as nx
# Preamble, define G1 

# contract nodes
for supernode in nx.connected_components(G1):
    nodes = sorted(list(supernode))
    for node in nodes[1:]:
        G1 = nx.contracted_nodes(G1, nodes[0], node)
```

Every node x in `G1` corresponds to the supernode having x as smaller element. If you want to remove self loops, write instead `nx.contracted_nodes(G1, nodes[0], node, self_loops=False)`.

Comment: The code will fun fine without `supernodes = list(nx.connected_components(G1))`  Just do `for supernode in nx.connected_components(G1):`

Answer (score 1):

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515216/14193020) answer, but it is too slow for big graphs. I discovered that converting the Networkx graph to DataFrame and combining the nodes on DataFrame is faster than the existing Networkx function.

```
import time
import networkx as nx

#create node replacement dictionary
def createRepDict(G1):

    node2supernode={}
    for supernode in nx.connected_components(G1):
        nodes = sorted(list(supernode))
        for node in nodes:
             node2supernode[node]=nodes[0]
    
    #fill the missing nodes with itself (if you have different task)
    for node in G1.nodes:
        if node not in node2supernode:
             node2supernode[node]=node
    return node2supernode

start_time=time.time()
for _ in range(10):
    G1=G.copy()
    df=nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G1)

    #create node replacement dictionary
    node2supernode=createRepDict(G1)
    
    df['source']=df.apply(lambda row: node2supernode[row['source']],axis=1)
    df['target']=df.apply(lambda row: node2supernode[row['target']],axis=1)

    # you can drop the self loop created after combining the nodes
    self_loop=df[df['source']==df['target']].index
    df=df.drop(self_loop)

    # edge_attr field can change based on your edge datas
    G1=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target', 
edge_attr='edgeData',create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

While this code takes only a total of 4 seconds for 10 random runs on a graph with around 5k nodes and 5k edges, it takes a total of 1455 seconds for 10 random runs with the existing methods.